# making a new column from another one in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 4 columns in my data set. first number of family, second number of persons in that family,  col3 is the number of trips that a person make, col4 the place of the activity of that person and col5 is something that I am want to make .

```
 family   persons    trip      activity       
     1     1        1         home
     1     1        2          work
     1     1        3          shopping
     1     1        4         home
     1     1        5         friends
     1     1        6          home
     1     2        1          home
     1     2        2           work
     1     2        3           home
```

as you can see in the above data set we have information of 2 persons in the first family. first person has 6 trips and the second one 3 trips. home is important in my analysis. I want to make loop based on home activity. in other words each loop is a set of activities that start at home and finish at home. for the first person we have 2 loops :

```
  first loop: home-> work -> shoping -> home
  second loop: home -> friends -> home
```

for second person we have 1 loop

```
   loop: home -> work -> home
```

I want to add a column that determine the number of loop in this data set like this :

```
family      persons    trip      place        loop
   1      1        1         home          1
   1      1        2          work         1
   1      1        3         shopping     1
   1      1        4         home          1  
   1      1        5         friends       2 
   1      1        6          home         2
   1      2        1          home         1
   1      2        2           work        1
   1      2        3           home        1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 'persons', 'family', create the index based on the occurrence of 'home' by getting the cumulative sum of logical vector and take the `lag` of the output

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(family, persons) %>% 
   mutate(loop = lag(cumsum(activity == "home"), default = 1))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   persons [2]
#  persons  trip activity  loop
#    <int> <int> <chr>    <dbl>
#1       1     1 home         1
#2       1     2 work         1
#3       1     3 shopping     1
#4       1     4 home         1
#5       1     5 friends      2
#6       1     6 home         2
#7       2     1 home         1
#8       2     2 work         1
39       2     3 home         1
```

Comment: if I have another column for family, should I group_by(family,person)?

Comment: please see edit, from your answer I realized it is important to mention that

Comment: @sherek_66. In that case you can use `family` as well in the grouping